Mosek Optimization log - BEST_INT_OBJ definition
When reading a Mosek MIP optimization log, e.g.
Presolved problem: 1176 variables, 1344 constraints, 4968 non-zeros
Presolved problem: 328 general integer, 392 binary, 456 continuous
Clique table size: 55
BRANCHES RELAXS   ACT_NDS  DEPTH    BEST_INT_OBJ         BEST_RELAX_OBJ       REL_GAP(%)  TIME
0        0        1        0        8.3888091139e+07     NA                   NA          0.0
0        1        1        0        8.3888091139e+07     2.5492512136e+07     69.61       0.1
0        1        1        0        3.1273162420e+07     2.5492512136e+07     18.48       0.1

what is the precise definition of BEST_INT_OBJ column? Is this the objective function value of the best feasible solution found for the primary problem (meaning the problem defined by the user, not the secondary problem that may be generated by the Presolver)?

It is what you write, ie. the objective value of the currently best integer solution.  https://docs.mosek.com/latest/capi/mip-optimizer.html#the-mixed-integer-log

Just to double-confirm - this objective value is for the solution for the problem defined by the user, NOT for the simplified problem generated by the Presolver?

Yes. Always from the user's point of view.
